# How could I cancel several requests with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, request, alamofire

I want to cancel some requests, but not all. 
Now I make like this:

```
func cancelAllRequests() {
    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in

        dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }

    }
}
```

, but it cancel all requests. How could I distinguish requests?

Comment: * I need to cancel request with same url, but how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this to cancel specific task if you know request or url

```
func cancellRequest(for request: URLRequest) {
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
        _ = tasks
            .filter({ $0.originalRequest?.url?.path == request.url?.path })
            .map({ $0.cancel() })
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I use my URL? And what to do .filter and .map?

Comment: Use you url like a parameter at function: cancellRequest(for url: URL). In filter in closure write this $0.originalRequest?.url == url. Closure in filter will compare each value in array with condition and will leave elements which equal condition in closure. Map fill apply contidion in your closure to each element in array

Comment: how do you use this in alamofire 5